# Record and play the same sound in python

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to record a sound of say 20 seconds and would simultaneously like to listen to the ongoing recording (obviously there would be some delay involved). So, I tried dividing my recording in slots of 5 seconds. Following is the code :

```
import os
for i in range(4):
    os.system("arecord -d 5 -r 22050 some_file.mp3")
    os.system("mplayer some_file.mp3 &")
```

However, I see that I have to wait for 5 sec initially and then the playing starts. But again after the 1st iteration, there's some delay and then playing starts. The playing is not continuous which I had assumed. Also the program hangs in the 4th iteration. Could any one please help me out in getting this right? Is there any other way to achieve my goal?
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Try naming the file differently in each pass (`some_file1.mp3`, `...2.mp3`, etc). `arecord` is probably truncating the file.

Comment: Hey thanks...that did work...But I was wondering if there is any other way I could do it..because the delay between stopping of playing one file and then playing the other is quite evident...